# Terraria map explanation

Tags: terraria

I generated my Terraria map using [MoreTerra](https://github.com/mike-mo/MoreTerra) and [TerraMap](https://terramap.codeplex.com/) and below is the image of the full map:

[image: My terraria map]

From the left what I see is, Ocean, Forest, Dungeon, Forest, Snow, Forest, Desert and so on. However, I do not see Crimson or Corruption. Are those missing in my map or are they available after progressing through the game?

Can someone point it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Corruption is that purple tunnely bit to the left and inside of the snow (see [the map view](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Corruption) on the wiki page, note you will probably get purple ice as well).

Crimson won't appear on this map as it is [either crimson or corruption generated per map](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Crimson) (First sentence in the link explains this).

**Your map biomes**

I would say it goes:

[Ocean](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Ocean), [Forest](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Forest), [Dungeon](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dungeon), [Corruption](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Corruption), [Snow](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Snow_biome) (+ 2 [Floating Islands](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Floating_Island) above), [Forest](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Forest), [Desert](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Desert), [Forest](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Forest), [Jungle](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Jungle) (+ 1 [Floating Island](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Floating_Island)), [Ocean](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Ocean).

Note many of the biomes also have a "deeper" biome section where there would be new enemies and treasures etc. to spawn.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I needed. I also did not notice that I also have forest biome.