# What are the coloured underground sections?

Tags: terraria

I recently saw [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/297787/terraria-map-explanation) asking about where the crimson or corruption was in their world, and the picture of their world that they included was the image below. Now I am not so familiar with the PC edition of the game as I am with the Xbox or mobile version - I only have about 25 hours played on Steam - so I never encountered some of the things on the map.

[image: World Map]

The first of these things is the sand coloured section of land under the normal desert. However, this is quite clearly some form of underground desert that is exclusive to PC. The confusion only arises upon looking at the somewhat, dark purple and light gray regions. (I'd have circled these on the image, however I'm unsure of how to do this)

From what I can see, there appears to be minecart track linking some of these sections, so possibly some form of abandoned mine. But, upon searching for this on the internet, all I could find was [this wiki entry](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Underground_Cabin) about underground cabins. These are most definitely not what I am looking for, as these are wooden structures and are on a much smaller scale to the other coloured regions on the map.

Then, as I didn't know what else to search for, to find an answer to this question, I came here to ask!

**So, what are the dark purple and light grey underground sections on the map?**

Comment: You should *really* circle the sections of the map you are talking about.

Comment: @TimmyJim I'm doing this on my iPhone. I would have liked to have done this, but do not know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are [Granite](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Granite_Cave) (Dark Purple) and [Marble](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Marble_Cave) (Light Grey) Caves. They each contain unique material which can be used to make unique furniture, and each have their own enemies with special drops.

Comment: Could you possibly expand on what these areas are useful for?

Comment: I've added a little bit about it, but that was what the wiki links were for.

Comment: There is an application called TEdit that allows you to view the entire world map (as you see above).  It's a bit of a spoiler but when you mouse over a section, you'll get an indicator to tell you what the material is.